# How to use the Workbox file service-worker.js correctly in a cra-template-pwa template create-react-app app?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I tried to use **create-react-app** both `3.4.1` and `4.0.0-next.77` (the two apps got generated have no difference) to create a new PWA app by

```
create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

The code is at https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/react-4-js-wb-test

There are two files related with service worker / Workbox.

- service-worker.js
- serviceWorkerRegistration.js

Here is original **service-worker.js**:

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

// Any other custom service worker logic can go here.
```

Based on the comment inside and [the official doc](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app.md), I think I should be able to customize Workbox.

I turned on service worker in **index.js** by changing `unregister()` to `register()`:

```
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';
serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
```

However, I cannot find any part of code using **service-worker.js**, so even I added

```
console.log('Workbox got called in service-worker.js');
```

inside, the `console.log` never got called neither in dev environment

```
yarn start
```

nor in prod environment

```
yarn build
serve build --ssl-cert ./my.crt --ssl-key ./my.key
```

I tried to add

```
import './service-worker';
```

on top of **index.js**

However, it will give me error

> not-an-array: The parameter 'entries' passed into 'workbox-precaching.PrecacheController.addToCacheList()' must be an array.

Based on the error, if I change `precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);` to `precacheAndRoute([self.__WB_MANIFEST]);`, the error becomes

> add-to-cache-list-unexpected-type: An unexpected entry was passed to 'workbox-precaching.PrecacheController.addToCacheList()' The entry 'undefined' isn't supported. You must supply an array of strings with one or more characters, objects with a url property or Request objects.

How can I use the Workbox file **service-worker.js** correctly? Thanks

---

**UPDATE**:

I found even I remove **src/service-worker.js**, and `yarn build` again, it will still generate a **build/service-worker.js** (content copy below) which is not related with original **src/service-worker.js** at all.

```
/**
 * Welcome to your Workbox-powered service worker!
 *
 * You'll need to register this file in your web app and you should
 * disable HTTP caching for this file too.
 *
 * The rest of the code is auto-generated. Please don't update this file
 * directly; instead, make changes to your Workbox build configuration
 * and re-run your build process.
 */

importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

importScripts(
  "/precache-manifest.e90b8a1c98bf449d45dd07f902f9c090.js"
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.core.clientsClaim();

/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 */
self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL("/index.html"), {
  
  blacklist: [/^\/_/,/\/[^/?]+\.[^/]+$/],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look inside serviceWorkerRegistration.js, there it's registering the service-worker:

```cs
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
```

AFAIK you cannot move this file (due to Workbox InjectManifest tool which is what replaces `self.__WB_MANIFEST` with the list of your static assets).

Everything works out-of-the-box after using the CRA with the right template (except of course for calling the `.register()` method).

I personally opted for not adding too much custom code in `src\service.worker.js` but rather importing my own in it (since it's transpiled you can then include anything you want).